# How to play video full screen on web page loading?

Tags: jquery, html, video, fullscreen

It need to be cross platform, I have developed this website  http://www.thereelthing.com.sg/ . the first view you will see a video will be shown. the issue is that i need this video be full screen on different browser, currently i have use fancy box and the video is load from http://vimeo.com/ to show it. but there is no limitation i can loading from my own server with any web player.

Thank you 
Note: This video set by cookie to just show in first visit of website.

Comment: Entering a fullscreen view has to be initiated by the user. It is a security feature...

Comment: is there any way i fire it by code, i have tried if the user press the "f" on the video, it will be full screen, but how can i fire "f" on fancybox loading? or is there any other way to do this?

Comment: @Danial - No! That is what "has to be initiated by the user" means.

Comment: @dan - if it was possible to bypass this feature it wouldn't be much of a security feature =)

Comment: You don't really want to do this anyway.  Even if it were possible, visitors to your site would hate you.  This will be especially true if your video has no real content, like the one there now.  Who wants to buffer something huge like that just to see your logo?

Comment: @Brad I totally agree with you from my point of view you are right, but my client are totally disagree:D , what do you suggest to me !?

Comment: @Danial, It's simple.  Explain to your client why it isn't possible to go full screen, and then suggest an A/B test... one without the video, and one with the video filling the view pane.  Prove to them with the resulting analytics data how poorly their site performs with a pointless video landing page.

Answer (score 2):

You could use some CSS, like this:

```css
#video { 
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    z-index: 100;
    -ms-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    -moz-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);

    z-index:300;
}
```

and use some JavaScrip so that it disappears:

```
setTimeout(hideDiv, 9000);
function hideDiv() {                   
    $("#video").fadeOut("slow");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It IS possible, I just don't recommend it. It's very invasive.
But if your client absolutely wants it, you could always utilize the [HTML5 fullscreen API](http://hacks.mozilla.org/2012/01/using-the-fullscreen-api-in-web-browsers/), which more and more browsers are adopting (Chrome/Firefox/Safari are some of the early adopters). You should look it up.

But it's important to note this this CANNOT be loaded onload (for security purposes), and has to be trigged by a user-trigged event, like "onclick". I suppose that onmouseover would be able to trigger it as well, (eg. well your mouse would hover over your client's webpage).

Sorry for the late response: I just discovered this thread.

Comment: thanks, but actually what they want they want on page load :|

Comment: @Danial and you coudn't use mouseover or something? Like mouseover loading bar to play video?

Comment: No actually, you there is a company that do not any experience with web :D. but i have already explain for them. i hope they really understand it.